# The upper bound for the max of absolute values of Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, absolute-value, upper-lower-bounds, expectation-maximization

Prove that $E[\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\vert X_i\vert]\leq C\sqrt{\log(2n)}\sigma$ for some constant $C \in R$, where $X_1, ..., X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$ are i.i.d.

Hint: Use Jensen's inequality: $f(E[Y])\leq E[f(Y)]$ for any convex function $f$.

I think that we can make use of the *moment-generating function*.
$$E[e^{\lambda X}]=e^{\sigma^2\lambda^2/2}$$
where $\lambda\in R$ is a constant, and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$.

Moreover, i have tried to use $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\vert X_i\vert\leq \sum_{i}^n \vert X_i\vert$, yet no good ideas.

Comment: The question is "wrong" in the following sense. With the requested bound, one only needs the assumption of subgaussian, no normality or independence assumption is needed at all! In any case, you are on the right track, just combine what you have with Jensen's inequality (premultiplying by $\lambda$).

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ and $\log$ using `\max` and `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @joriki Thank you! I have already edited the probelm.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\lambda>0.$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq N}X_i]&=\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{\lambda}\log e^{\lambda\max_{1\leq i\leq N}X_i}]\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\log\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda\max_{1\leq i\leq N}X_i}]\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\log\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq N}e^{\lambda X_i}]\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\log\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X_i}]\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\log \sum_{i=1}^Ne^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2}\\
&=\frac{\log n}{\lambda}+\frac{\lambda\sigma^2}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $\lambda=\sqrt{2(\log N)/\sigma^2}$, we can get $\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq N}X_i]\leq \sqrt{2\sigma^2\log n}$

Moreover, there is a fact that $\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\vert X_i\vert=\max_{1\leq i\leq 2N}X_i$, where $X_{N+i}=-X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$
Thus $\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq N}\vert X_i\vert]\leq \sqrt{2\log (2N)}\sigma=C\sqrt{\log(2  N)}\sigma$